# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requeste

Tags: angular, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, unauthorized, chalice

```
- BUG: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://*.execute-api.*.amazonaws.com/api' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requeste
```

> - I have implemented Enable CORS on AWS API GATEWAY.
> - At the Backend we use chalice (Python), each API returns the body as follows:

```
Response(
            status_code=200,
            body={
                'name_pharmacy': data['name'],
                'pharmacy_id': data['id']
            },
            headers={
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With'
            }
        )
```

```
However we can't get past the CORS . error
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid CORS errors, you should proxy the calls so that the application always calls itself, then the proxy takes care of redirecting the calls.

So, first we create the `proxy.conf.json`.

touch proxy.conf.json`

Inside it we put an initial configuration, e.g:

```js
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

In the `package.json` we modify the start command:

`"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json"`

Restart the application and we're there!

[here](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server) you can read about the proxy.

Enjoy!